# JSF Can't resolve Converter ID from backing bean in an h:dataTable

Tags: java, jsf, facelets, converters

I have a dynamic data table in JSF which has multiple input elements which can be of various data types.  The input is always a text control, but can contain numeric or text data.  To handle this, each field retrieves its converterId from the backing bean:

```
<h:dataTable id="indexFieldTable" value="#{indexFieldBean.indexField}" var="item">
  <h:column id="column">

    <h:inputText id="inputID" value="#{item.value}">
      <f:converter id="ifConverter" converterId="#{item.converter}" />
      <f:validator id="ifValidator" validatorId="#{item.validator}" />
    </h:inputText>
  </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

However, when this is rendered, I get this error: `Expression Error: Named Object: ' not found.`

If I hard code the converterId to a known value, it works fine:

```
<f:converter id="ifConverter" converterId="stringConverter" />
```

How can I dynamically configure the converterId?

Comment: are you sure `item.converter` is not empty?

Comment: I'm positive.  I added <h:outputText value="#{item.converter}" /> to be sure, and the correct value appears.

Comment: Just checking - item.converter is String type right?

Comment: If I use "#{indexFieldBean.converter0}" it works properly (getConverter0() is a function that returns getIndexField()[0].getConverter() in the backing bean)...  However this hard-coded to return the first converter rather than the dynamic one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `f:` tags are specific to the component, not to the iterated item. At view build time (when the components get populated in component tree of the view), the `#{item}` isn't available. It's only available during render time. You really need to attach their values to the parent bean, not the iterated item.

To fix this, first alter the `Field` class (which is represented by `#{item}`) to have fullworthy `Converter` and `Validator` properties (you could just create them upon `Field`'s construction).

```
public class Field {
    private Converter converter;
    private Validator validator;

    // ...
}
```

Then alter the bean to wrap the collection of those fields in a [`DataModel`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/model/DataModel.html) and have generic convert/validate methods which delegates to the currently iterated item in the `DataModel` which is available by `DataModel#getRowData()`:

```
public class Bean {
    private List<Field> fields;
    private DataModel<Field> fieldModel;

    public Bean() {
        fields = loadItSomehow();
        fieldModel = new ListDataModel<Field>(fields);
    }

    public Converter getFieldConverter() {
        return fieldModel.getRowData().getConverter();
    }

    public void validateField(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) throws ValidatorException {
        fieldModel.getRowData().getValidator().validate(context, component, value);
    }

    // ...
}
```

Finally change the input field in the view as follows to bind the `h:dataTable`'s value to the `DataModel` and the converter/validator to those of the parent bean which in turn delegates the call to the currently iterated item:

```
<h:dataTable value="#{bean.fieldModel}" var="field">
    <h:column>
        <h:inputText value="#{field.value}" converter="#{bean.fieldConverter}" validator="#{bean.validateField}" />
        ...
```

Noted should be that this complexity is not due to the nature of JSF, but due to the very specific functional requirement you have there. Normally, the `h:dataTable` is to be used to represent tabluar data, not to generate a dynamic form.

Comment: After seeing your edit, this seems to be working.  Out of curiosity, do you know why converter expects a Converter, while validator expects a method that validates?  As is evidenced by your code before the edit, it seems inconsistent.

Comment: Maybe because the converter has two methods and the validator only one. It's after all easier to bind to a method directly.